# Converting TIMESTAMP to unix time in PHP?

Tags: php, timestamp, unix-timestamp, epoch

Currently I store the time in my database like so: `2010-05-17 19:13:37`

However, I need to compare two times, and I feel it would be easier to do if it were a unix timestamp such as `1274119041`. (These two times are different)

So how could I convert the timestamp to unix timestamp? Is there a simple php function for it?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You're looking for [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Comment: Thanks this did the trick...but.. For somereason MySQL's NOW() is giving off a different time than TIME(). Any ideas about that?

Comment: meh, nevermind. I set a variable to time() and inserted that into the database rather than NOW(). Thanks anyway

Answer (score 16):

You want [strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime):

```
print strtotime('2010-05-17 19:13:37'); // => 1274123617
```

Answer (score 7):

Getting a unixtimestamp:

```
$unixTimestamp = time();
```

Converting to mysql datetime format:

```
$mysqlTimestamp = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $unixTimestamp);
```

Getting some mysql timestamp:

```
$mysqlTimestamp = '2013-01-10 12:13:37';
```

Converting it to a unixtimestamp:

```
$unixTimestamp = strtotime('2010-05-17 19:13:37');
```

...comparing it with one or a range of times, to see if the user entered a realistic time:

```
if($unixTimestamp > strtotime("1999-12-15") && $unixTimestamp < strtotime("2025-12-15"))
{...}
```

Unix timestamps are safer too. You can do the following to check if a url passed variable is valid, before checking (for example) the previous range check:

```
if(ctype_digit($_GET["UpdateTimestamp"]))
{...}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're using MySQL as your database, it can return date fields as unix timestamps with [UNIX_TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp):

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(my_datetime_field)
```

You can also do it on the PHP side with [strtotime](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):

```
strtotime('2010-05-17 19:13:37');
```

Answer (score 2):

if you store the time in the database, why don't you let the database also give you the unix timestamp of it? see [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp), eg.

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date) ...;
```

databases can also do date and time comparisons and arithmetic.