# PHP: Convert epoch to MySQL DateTime format

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have to store epoch timestamps into a MySQL database DateTime column. I need to be able to convert the epoch into the DateTime form to be able to add it to the database. The epoch data is grabbed from an external source so we have no control over that, the database is also established and should be left as it is. We just need to be able to convert between the two in PHP.

Comment: There're many [epochs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_%28reference_date%29)... I presume you mean [Unix epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) :-?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**PHP**

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$epochTS);
```

**MySQL**

```
FROM_UNIXTIME(timestampColumn)
```

Nothing more to it

Comment: Many thanks, the PHP you have expresses the date exactly as it is in the database,

Answer (score 0):

No need to do any convert for MySQL or PHP just or enter the same to database

```
echo date('r', $epoch);
```

`strotime()` is the function used to convert datetime to epoch. [Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Answer (score 0):

`strotime()` is the function used to convert datetime to epoch. [Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

`time()` is the function used to convert epoch to datetime. [Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php)

Comment: also read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850624/converting-timestamp-to-unix-time-in-php).